# CSS minifier to remove vendor prefixes

Tags: css

I am looking for a CSS minifier (or minifier option) which would remove all the vendor prefixes, expecting all CSS3 to be working without prefix.

Here are the reasons:

- I intend to use [prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) which allow to add those vendors on the fly, client-side
- I do not expect handling browsers where javascript would be disabled
- The main goal is to have the smallest CSS
- Another goal is to not handle vendors in my CSS files, and I do not want Sass mixins or Stylus to add them automatically
- I want a minifier so that I can use any library like Foundation or Bootstrap **without** modifying them

So, are there any minifier out there supporting such an option, or a standalone minifier which I could use to, given some input files (or stream), get output CSS files (or stream) without the prefixed properties, only the standard CSS property?

Comment: Don't use prefix-free, adds a ton of time to your page load.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it depends the size of the css, and if so then some work/PR can be done there to improve prefix-free speed. Anyway, my question remains ;-)

Comment: Also I think that if you have only one CSS file with all inside, no inline CSS, and a one page application, that doesn't matter too much, and that is my case. The processing will take place when loading the page, but then since it's a OPA no more further processing, only one time processing.

Comment: Take a look at [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) it may help.

Comment: I don't want to **add** prefixes, but I want to **remove** them

Comment: I think you're looking for a 'linter' not a minifier, but i don't know any that wipes -vendor-prefixes, they only make sure you add them all.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. And yeah most of them can add prefixes but not remove them :( – I actually began to write one hehe

Answer (score 0):

So, as I couldn't find anything, I did my own CSS vendor de-prefixer. Here is the source, still a prototype, but working and usable:

https://github.com/huafu/css-devendorize